# Columns are added in wrong order

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I have a encountered strange behaviour adding columns to an existing table. I run those scripts using osql several instances.

Let Table `a_table` have initially three columns `A_col`, `B_col` and `C_col`.

To extend this table I use the following statements:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE COLUMN_NAME = N'D_col' AND TABLE_NAME = N'a_table')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[a_table] ADD [D_col] int DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL
END
```

Up to now this script worked fine. I have a script adding two batches of columns (15 each) separated with a `GO` statement.

```
IF NOT ... -- col 1
...
END
:
:
IF NOT ... -- col 15
...
END
GO

IF NOT ... -- col 16
...
END
:
:
IF NOT ... -- col 30
...
END
GO
```

I expect the columns 1-15 to be added first and 16-30 second. But it happens from time to time that the second batch gets executed first so the columns appear in the wrong order (16-30, 1-15).

Any explanation for this behaviour is appreciated!

Comment: This would mean batch 2 is run before batch 1, no?

Comment: I assume this. Although it would be really weird as both batches are in a single file!

Comment: do you have the same table is 2 different schema eg dbo.table1 and wtf.table1?

Comment: No. It's all in one schema and there is just one schema.

Comment: How are you running the scripts?  In SSMS?

Comment: I'm running them during an update procedure that calls osql with the -i parameter.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: MSSQL express 2k5.

Comment: How frequently is it reversed?  1/10 runs, 1/100, 1/10000?

Comment: The update ran just on some test (lab / early adaptor) machines. It went wrong in about 10 out of 20 runs. It occurs just on few tables (all with similar structure, >100 columns, all int, bit or char(16)).

Comment: That doesn't seem terribly surprising to me.  You're doing column adds, so the batches are having to get schema locks and if for some reason, the second batch compiles faster, or they both get blocked waiting to get the lock and the second one jumps in first, well, it wins.

You aren't guaranteed order of statement operations between batches, only internal to a batch.

Comment: This explanation fits the situation and if it would match my experience I would totally agree.

Comment: Sorry, last comment containt only a part of the statement. Here is the rest: This explanation fits the situation and if it would match my experience I would totally agree. For example if you run two while loops adding up integers each in one batch. The first batch runs to 1000000, the second just to 100. I never got the second result first. Or if you use SSMS to generate a "create table"-script you'll find a lot of `GO` statements where a reordering would have fatal effects.

Comment: Incidentally, you should not care what order columns are in for a particluar table. If you have correctly written your SQL, you have specified the columns in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we were able to sort it out: It was a `GO` in a block comment `/* ... GO ... */`.

We tested the code in SSMS were the `GO` is ignored (as it is in a block comment). osql does not ignore it! We had the two batches in this block comment in a previous update. The first was ignored. The second was executed because the GO in the comment broke the comment.

Thanks to @gbn, @JNK and @Brandon for their help!